# Refer dependent JARs of Junit project on GitHub triggered by Jenkins

Tags: github, jenkins, junit, jar

I have a Junit test suite which depends on around 30 JARs. The Junit source code is on GitHub and I want to trigger the test suite from Jenkins. I can do this by using GitHub plugin. I.e. using Fressstyle project and then selecting source code management as GitHub.

Now my Junit itself depends on around 30 JARs. These are not present on GitHub. So cannot use sub-module option. They reside on our application server.

My question is:- How do I refer these when Junit runs? Should I upload all of these 30 JARs to GitHub (seems incorrect). Is there a way? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Use a tool for building your software that handles the dependency management. E.g. Ant with Ivy, Maven or Gradle. Otherwise you have to reinvent the wheel.